PrismaClientValidationError: Invalid `prisma.roomMember.create()` invocation
If I attempt to create a room without including a RoomMember, everything works as expected. However, when I try to create a member using the createRoomAction, I encounter the following error message:
Error Message:


Invalid prisma.roomMember.create() invocation:

{
  data: {
    emailAddress: "alhendisaid@gmail.com",
    role: "admin",
    name: "Said",
    userId: "user_2eUSQ4tHpc5dlmeNpqhYu27k3gT",
    roomId: "19058849-924f-4805-ba40-3c8513be5ed5",
    ~~~~~~
?   id?: String,
?   createdAt?: DateTime,
?   updatedAt?: DateTime
  }
}


Unknown argument roomId. Available options are marked with ?.

my createRoomAction looks like this:
export async function createRoomAction(values: createAndEditRoomType): Promise<RoomType | null> {
    const { id: userId, emailAddresses, firstName } = await authenticateAndRedirect();
    const emailAddress = emailAddresses[0]?.emailAddress || "";
    const AdminName = firstName || "";

    try {
        const room = await prisma.room.create({
            data: {
                ...values,
                clerkId: userId,
                emailAddress: emailAddress
            }
        });

        const admin = await prisma.roomMember.create({
            data: {
                emailAddress: emailAddress,
                role: "admin",
                name: AdminName,
                userId,
                roomId: room.id, 
            }
        });

        return room;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Fehler beim Erstellen des Admins:", error);
        return null;
    }
}

my prisam schema looks like this
model Room {
        id String @id @db.Uuid @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()"))
        name String
        clerkId String
        type String
        controller String
        autoRevealCards Boolean
        showAveraging Boolean
        emailAddress String
        createdAt DateTime @default(dbgenerated("now()"))
        updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
        roomMember RoomMember[]
    }
    model RoomMember{
        id String @id @db.Uuid @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()"))
        name String
        emailAddress String
        userId String
        role Role
        roomId String @db.Uuid
        room Room @relation(fields: [roomId] , references: [id])
        createdAt DateTime @default(dbgenerated("now()"))
        updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
    }

I want the creator of a room to be also a member of the room and each room has several members that means in later time I will create several members for each room and they should be connected to the id of the room.
How can I solve this?

Why not use a nested write instead of two separate inserts?
const room = await prisma.room.create({
  // Optional: include the room member in the response
  include: {
    roomMember: true,
  },
  data: {
    name: 'Test Room',
    // .. all the other fields
    clerkId: userId,
    emailAddress: emailAddress,
    // Create a member and assign them to the room
    roomMember: {
      create: {
        emailAddress,
        name: adminName,
        userId,
      },
    },
  },
});


